# Can C# return a type in a method?

Tags: c#

can i have something like:

```
AMess.Foo = MessyData.GetData<MessyData.GetType(key)>(key);
```

?

my problem is similar to my example. I have a data source is dynamically typed, so i have to do something to determine the data type. but it's a pain in the ass to put type check everywhere. so i think maybe i could have some code just to tell me what type it is. can i do this?

or maybe better solution?

please not worry about `AMess.Foo`, it eats everything.

Comment: If it eats anything, why not return an object, and not need the generic signature?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't. You'll have to use Reflection instead. I don't have Visual Studio installed on my machine at the moment so I can't test the syntax at the moment, but this should be close:

```
var type = MessyData.GetType(key);
var castMethod = MessyData.GetType().GetMethod("GetData").MakeGenericMethod(type);
AMess.Foo = castMethod.Invoke(MessyData, new[] { key });
```

Comment: What about returning the value of `typeof(T)`?

Comment: That still returns an instance of `Type` and can't be used in Generics with Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

No. Generic type arguments must be resolved at compile-time.

If you use:

```
MessyData.GetData<SomeType>(key);
```

then `SomeType` needs to be the name of a specific class (or interface, struct, etc.). It can never be an *expression* like in your question.

If you let the type be inferred, as in:

```
MessyData.GetData(key); // infer type arg
```

then the type used in the call is the compile-time type of the `key` variable, *not* the run-time type. These types can differ.

If you really want dynamic typing, you can have `GetData` take in a parameter of type `dynamic` (the method will be non-generic). But what is the problem you are trying to solve?